# Как подключиться к Mysql openserver c помощью Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, openserver

Здравствуйте, кто нибудь может объяснить  как подкл. к базе Mysql openserver с помощью Qt. Код не работает, все время false:

```
 QSqlDatabase db0 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db0.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db0.setPort(3306);
    db0.setDatabaseName("bsproducts");
    db0.setUserName("root");
    db0.setPassword("");
    if (db0.open()) {
        qDebug() <<"Yra vishlo :)";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "yvi :(";

    }
```

Comment: Какое сообщение от БД при ошибке вы получаете?

Comment: А я не знаю как его получить, я знаю есть lastError() но не знаю как его в строку перевести

Comment: lastError().databaseText() и lastError().driverText() посмотрите.

Comment: Все разобрался как выводить вот что написало: "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

Comment: Скорее всего, вам придётся самостоятельно скомпилировать драйвер базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (db0.open()) {
        qDebug() <<"Yra vishlo :)";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "yvi :("<<db0.lastError().text();
    }
```

;( не успел ...

Comment: Чего не успели?

Answer (score 0):

Все решил проблему. Проблема была из-за того, что Qt требовал драйвер для базы данных. Как я понял его надо собирать, но можно поступить проще в OpenServer он уже лежит по пути  G:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\lib  Вместо MySQL-5.6 ставите свою б.д вам нужен файл libmysql.dll копируем его к exe файлу вашей программы, как вариант можно его записать в PATH в глобальные переменные окружения. Подключение у меня правильное, можете использовать кому надо, не хватало драйвера.